# Matplotlib have Histogram legend be dashes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Out of curiosity, does anyone know how to make the legend of a histogram plot similar to that of a line plot?  I am calculating the PDF and its better to overlay lines. However the legend is still boxes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

# Create scatter plot



ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.02))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.2f}')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))


ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter('{x:.0f}')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))


ax.tick_params(which='minor', width=1, length=5, color='black')

ax.tick_params(which='major', width=1)

plt.xlim(0,22.0)
ax.hist(one, bins=15, density=True, stacked = True, lw=2, histtype='step',  label ='label')
.
.
.
.
ax.hist(four, bins=15, density=True, stacked = True, lw=2, histtype='step',  label ='label')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `np.histogram` to compute the bins and histogram, then plot with `step` function:

```
# create the axis instance
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# loop through the columns
for col in ['En1','En2']:

    # compute the histogram
    hist,bins = np.histogram(CA_Coast_Jan[col],bins=15, density=True)

    # plot histogram as step function
    ax.step(bins, [0]+hist.tolist(), label=col)
    
plt.legend()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create dummy line plots with single data points on the x-axis solely for the purpose of using their legends.  See the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

ax.hist(df.col1, bins=4, density=True, stacked=True, lw=2, histtype='step', color = 'orange')
ax.hist(df.col2, bins=4, density=True, stacked=True, lw=2, histtype='step', color = 'cyan')

#dummy line plots:
ax.plot(2,0, label='first dataset', color = 'orange')
ax.plot(2,0, label='second dataset', color = 'cyan')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]